# replace the string from the html file that is inserted into the string variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, string

I have a code to convert a string into a new string that is derived from a variable

```
const htmlstring = fs.readFileSync(config.message.letter);


function replace_tags(input, email) {
    return input
    .replace("{randomip}", random.ip)
    .replace("{email}", email)
    .replace("{date}", random.date);
}


function get_customised_message_template(email) {
    return {
        subject: replace_tags(config.message.subject, email),
        fromname: replace_tags(config.message.fromname, email),
        fromemail: replace_tags(config.message.fromemail, email),
        html: replace_tags(htmlstring, email) // >> here the error
    };
}
```

here I want to replace the string inside the HTML file that I enter into the htmlstring variable using readfilesync

the sample in HTML file

```
<b>mati lu anjeng {email} {randomip}</b>
```

I need to replace the tag like the others using the replace_tags() function
but I get this error

```
(node:4784) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: input.replace is not a function
```

what should I do to outsmart it

Comment: is `random` some global object?

Comment: It would be better if you can create a fiddle of your problem.

Comment: random is object in another file

Comment: can you copy whole code with place where you call that `get_customised_message_template` method?? Otherwise it s not clear how you use it. 
Other than this, I would say that  you should pass all the variables you use inside a method as a parameters to that method. 
So your method will look like: `get_customised_message_template(htmlString, email, config)`. 
Will also be easier to debug this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might possibly be because `.readFileSync` returns a buffer and not a string and `.replace` method is a string method. so try to convert the read buffer into a `utf8` encoded string as below

```
const htmlstring = fs.readFileSync(config.message.letter)
                     .toString('utf8');
```

Answer (score 0):

You got this error because `fs.readFileSync()` retuns a byte buffer by default and `replace` is a function of string type. You would need to either covert the buffer into a string as in @Abdulfatai answer or specify the encoding while reading the file like below:

```
const htmlstring = fs.readFileSync(config.message.letter, 'utf-8');
```

Comment: Thats shorter and faster, nice one `@Swatantra Jain`.